# Showing recently viewed products on the basket page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

Is it possible to show recently viewed products in the basket?

i.e. a customer views product a, product b and product c.

They add product b to their basket.

When they view their basket I would like to show product a and product c underneath their basket.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add in code below in your basket layout page.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

For CMS use code below

```
{{block type="reports/product_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}
```

Comment: That works! But do you know how to exclude items currently in the basket from the block?